# remove target and rel attributes from links with yahoo pipes regex

Tags: regex, href, pipe, yahoo, target

I'm trying to remove rel and target attributes from a RSS description using regex but can't seem to figure it out. I'm able to remove classes and styles, but rel and target just won't work. I've tried quite a few ways with [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) that work there, but do not work when I bring them over to Pipes.

I've tried...

`<a(.*?) target="(.*?)"` replacing with `<a$1`

which works in when re-engineered to remove classes or styles from tags, but not this?

Any suggestions??

Here's a sample...

```
<p>Find out more at <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://someurl.org/">someurl.org</a>. </p>
```

Which I would like to be

```
<p>Find out more at <a href="http://someurl.org/">someurl.org</a>. </p>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and maybe expected output?

Comment: @DavidStarkey, I just updated my original question to include a sample and expected output.

Comment: update: it seems even hard coding a generic URL href will still add the rel="nofollow" target="_blank" to the link. Is this just something we have to deal with??

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
(.*)rel=".*" target=".*" (.*)
```

Then your replace would just use `\1\2` or whatever the software uses to do the replacing.

Example:

http://regexr.com?353i5

Comment: yes it works just fine on regexr.com, but for some reason Yahoo Pipes does not recognize it?? Here's the pipe that I'm working on, http://pipes.yahoo.com/slcschools/8fbec2724abc6e1b704d6fb6923151cf. As you can see, the rel and target remain in the link at the bottom of the description...

Comment: What browser are you using?  I only see the `target="_blank"` (Firefox 20) which is likely not caused by the pipes, but rather Yahoo or the Browser, directing the link to open in a new page/tab.

Comment: using FF21. I am looking at the markup within Pipes' debugger output pane, which is identical to what's being pulled into my feed-reader code...

Comment: Can't you do the replace in your feed-reader then?  My guess would be Yahoo is trying to open links (that are not Yahoo) in different windows in order to keep users on their site.  No official source, but my assumption.

Comment: that's what I'm looking into now. I think you're right too about links within their feeds... just from what I've searched so far, I think I'll do some sort of jquery find and replace once the page loads.

Comment: Yep, I think that's gonna be the best way for me :) Already have it working. Thanks for your help @David!